# create Listview without using listactivity.only use activty

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity

I know how can implement listview without using listactivity.But i dont know how get the clicked item from the listview.Please anyone tell me how listen the clicked item from the listview without using listactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Follow this [Link](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-example). Here you can find simple Listview example using Activity.

Using `listview.setOnItemClickListener` you can get Click on Listview.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                    long id) 
            {



            }
```

Comment: your link expained only the listactivty extended way

Comment: Thanks for your help...got answer ..using adapter.getItemAtPosition(position)

Answer (score 0):

You can implements `OnItemClickListener` and can write the method like below or just simply use eclipse to implement unimplemented method

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
            long id) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make instance of list view Clickable like

```
lv.setClickable(true);
```

then
use following

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                    long id) 
            {



            }
```

Comment: just use `position` which integer. this will tell you that which Item you have clicked

Comment: the above link fully explained using extends the listactivty.

Comment: Thanks for your help...got answer ..using adapter.getItemAtPosition(position)

Answer (score 0):

use ListView.

Then with the listview object invoke

```
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,    long arg3) {
           //do your stuff
   }
  }
```

Comment: arg2 is the index of the adapter you have clicked.

Comment: yourAdapter.get(arg2) will return the clicked item

Comment: not contain any function like "yourAdapter.get(position)".No get() method in my adapter

Comment: Thanks for your help...got answer ..using adapter.getItemAtPosition(position)

Answer (score 0):

for click on listview in activiyt try this code...

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                //write you action here


            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help...got answer ..using adapter.getItemAtPosition(position)